# Some level of security with registry and c#

Tags: c#, .net, security, search, registry

In the setup i add this registry file like the image below.For security issues i dont want someone to copy the folder of the software and put it on other pc and work this is why added this file.

All i want is in my form 1 (main) on load to check if the registry file exists to be able to continue with the program else terminate.
Do i need a for loop?

If you have any better suggestions let me know.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

       RegistryKey MyReg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
        ("HKLM\\Software\\[Manufacturer]\\checkup");
        if (MyReg.ValueCount == 1)
        { }

        else{ MessageBox.Show("error");
       }


        }
```

[image: Registry added]

do i have to put any value on the checkup?

[image: properties of checkup file]

**Any help will be appreciated**

Comment: What actually is your problem ? Have you read the MSDN documentation on the Microsoft.Win32.Registry ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: My problem is because for the first time i am trying to do that i dont know how.Yes i had a look in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(VS.80).aspx) . If i knew how to do it i wasn't going to make a question..

Comment: i have updated my code with what i tried. but i dont know if this works or no. @PhillipH

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign the value of the registry to an *object*. :

```
object key_value = key.GetValue("Version");
```